# Keys in Perl hash disappeared

Tags: perl, hash, key

I have a list of data that I want to put into a Perl hash

**file** `missing_rs.txt`

```
rs11273140
rs79236118
rs63414861
rs11414981
...
```

So I built a `while` loop

```
#! usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my (%hash1, %hash2, %hash3); #%hash1, %hash3 are for other purposes
open (my $FH2, '<', 'missing_rs.txt') or die $!;

my $count2 = 0;
while ( my $line2 = <$FH2> ) {
        chomp $line2;
        my @key2 = split /\t/, $line2;
        $hash2{$key2[0]} = 1;
        $count2++;
}

my @missing_rs_keys = keys %hash2; # added to help troubleshoot
my @missing_rs_values = values %hash2; # added to help troubleshoot
my $item;
print "@missing_rs_keys"; 

my $missing_rs = scalar @missing_rs_keys; #added to help troubleshoot
print "Total missing rs (non-redundant) count is $count2\n"; # added to help troubleshoot
print "Total number of missing rs after buidling hash is $missing_rs\n"; # added to help troubleshoot
```

My question is, why can I not `print` the `%hash2` keys, as the output from `print "@missing_rs_keys";` is empty but `$missing_rs = 20`.

I tried to build a `foreach` loop to print out each key in `%hash2`, and the loop ran well and gave me what I expected, but somehow I could not `print "@missing_rs_keys"` directly.

**Update**

When I ran the script I got this output

```
[chenb07@minerva4 ~]$ perl crazy2
Total missing rs (non-redundant) count is 23
Total number of missing rs after buidling hash is 20
[chenb07@minerva4 ~]$
```

Comment: I do not know how this is empty in your case . This same code with sample data provided by you is giving me keys i.e. `rs11273140 rs79236118 rs63414861 rs11414981`

Comment: Do your lines begin with a tab?

Comment: Inspect your actual file using: `od -c missing_rs.txt | head`

Comment: my output shows only 'Total missing rs (non-redundant) count is 23' and 'Total number of missing rs after building hash is 20'.

Comment: @BChen I think you should explain why are you splitting using `\t` and if your file contains more text then what you put here then you should put that here too. Also it does not make sense if you are able to print using `foreach` then why is `interpolation` not working for you. I do not think this has anything to do with your code. Are you able to print  `array` this way in some other code?

Comment: Does your input end in `\r\n`?

Comment: `print "@array";` is not great for debugging; do `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print Dumper \@array;` instead. Even better, simply dump the hash itself: `print Dumper \%hash2;`

Comment: @shivams, new to perl so any comment could be off the mark. but unless `\t` could affect the output, i doubt it's causing the trouble. `\t` was used in other `hashes` so i just kept it. as you already pointed out, it is not needed for `hash2`. I did wrete a small script just to test `print @array` for general purpose and it went well. That's why I said I was about to go berserk because I could NOT figure out why this particular script refuses to print the array.

Comment: @mob when i ran the code per suggestion from kjpires, the output does end in `\r \n r`. What does that mean? @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, I am a newbie for language so I cannot fully grasp what you suggested. Will google them and try. Thanks

Comment: `\r` is a carriage return character that moves the cursor to the beginning of the current line without advancing to the next line. Printing `"@missing_rs_keys"` when every element of that array ends in `\r` will just print all the elements on top of each other. Instead of `chomp($line2)`, say `$line2 =~ s/\s+$//`.

Comment: this is the (partial) output after I run `od -c missing_rs.txt | head` `0000000   r   s   1   1   2   7   3   1   4   0  \r  \n   r   s   7   9
0000020   2   3   6   1   1   8  \r  \n   r   s   6   3   4   1   4   8`

Comment: @mob, are you suggesting that my output data just happens to be incompatible with my "environment" so `rs` gets reinterpreted ?? but if so, how could I get the `rs` output when I use a `foreach` loop to "force" printing the `keys`

Comment: Then print an `\n` after each element, e.g. `print join("\n",@missing_rs_keys)`

Answer (score 1):

You are processing a Windows text file in a non-Windows environment, so your `chomp` is removing the trailing linefeed on each record but leaving the carriage-return. That has the effect of making each line of output on the console overwrite the preceding one so it appears as if there is nothing in the array

Just replace your `chomp` with `s/\s+\z//` and all will be well

Comment: I am just curious here. Why is this not effecting when print is done with `foreach`. As per question `foreach` is giving keys. Is this carriage-return thingy only work on interpolating array? Why is this different behaviour?

Comment: @shivams: Because you presumably printed a newline after each array element. Something like `print "$_\n" for @missing_rs_keys` would output separate lines

Comment: So if do `print "$_"  for @missing_rs_keys` then i will face the same issue of not getting anything on output.

Comment: @shivams: Yes. Why don't you try it?